# Does Deepsleep (Standby mode) resets uptime?

Tags: sleep-wake

Recently, I noticed that my MacBook Pro retina 15" 2015 mid takes a quite long time to wake up from sleep.

Today, I realized that my machine didn't *wake* up but actually *boots* up. How did I know that? I've just typed `uptime` command from a Terminal.app right after the screen shows up.

It says, for example,

> 1:25 up 3 mins, ...

That means, my machine has been running for only 3 minutes and it does not take time before sleep into account.

Then, only one explanation is possible. *My machine has been shut down between sleep and wake. And I misunderstood its new boot as wake up*

Another rationale is, Deepsleep (Standby mode) resets uptime counter. Huh...

Which do you think more legit?

Answer (score 4):

Your Mac is effectively shut down during the deeper sleep modes. The system state is stored as a file and then the Mac is shut down. On powering back on, the system state is restored from the file.

It is this behaviour that is most likely resetting your `uptime` results. At the lower UNIX level, most tools will treat the interval as time where your Mac was powered off.

You can learn more about the various sleep states in Apple's [OS X: Saving energy with Sleep](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202824). Deep sleep is mentioned in the **Standby Mode** section:

> ### Standby Mode
>
> For Mac computers that are started from an solid-state drive, OS X includes a deep sleep mode known as Standby Mode. Mac computers manufactured in 2013 or later enter standby after one to three hours of regular sleep. A computer with a fully charged battery can remain in standby for up to thirty days without being plugged in to an AC power source.